# Javascript: using a wildcard character with a replace method

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a String that contains a line of html code eg. `'<b>1995</b>'`. Let's say this String could also contain `'<b>1997</b>'` or `'<b>1999</b>'` etc. I want to use a replace method to remove the tags but leave the years. Is there a way to implement a wildcard character to do this, something like:

```
first_string = "First year is <b>1997</b> and second year is <b>1999</b>"
second_string = first_string.replace(/<b>19.*<\/b>/g, 19.*)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
first_string.replace(/<b>(19\d{2})<\/b>/g, '$1')
```